# Share config files with spark-submit in cluster mode

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, hadoop-yarn

I've been running my spark jobs in "client" mode during development. I use "--file" to share config files with executors. Driver was reading config files locally. Now I want to deploy the job in "cluster" mode. I'm having difficulty sharing the config files with driver now.

Ex, I'm passing the config file name as extraJavaOptions to both driver and executors. I'm reading the file using SparkFiles.get()

```
  val configFile = org.apache.spark.SparkFiles.get(System.getProperty("config.file.name"))
```

This works well on the executors but fails on driver. I think the files are only shared with executors and not with the container where driver is running.
One option is to keep the config files in S3. I wanted to check if this can be achieved using spark-submit.

```
> spark-submit --deploy-mode cluster --master yarn --driver-cores 2
> --driver-memory 4g --num-executors 4 --executor-cores 4 --executor-memory 10g \
> --files /home/hadoop/Streaming.conf,/home/hadoop/log4j.properties \
> --conf **spark.driver.extraJavaOptions**="-Dlog4j.configuration=log4j.properties
> -Dconfig.file.name=Streaming.conf" \
> --conf **spark.executor.extraJavaOptions**="-Dlog4j.configuration=log4j.properties
> -Dconfig.file.name=Streaming.conf" \
> --class ....
```

Comment: I faced something similar, posted the answer here. I hope it would help someone. https://stackoverflow.com/a/62095856/1929092

Answer (score 5):

I found a solution for this problem in [this](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Advanced-Analytics-Apache-Spark/Spark-job-fails-in-cluster-mode/m-p/58772) thread.

You can give an alias for the file you submitted through --files by adding '#alias' at the end. By this trick, you should be able to access the files through their alias.

For example, the following code can run without an error.

```
spark-submit --master yarn-cluster --files test.conf#testFile.conf test.py
```

with test.py as:

```
path_f = 'testFile.conf'
try:
    f = open(path_f, 'r')
except:
    raise Exception('File not opened', 'EEEEEEE!')
```

and an empty test.conf

Answer (score 4):

You need to try the `--properties-file` option in Spark submit command.

**For example properties file content**

```
spark.key1=value1
spark.key2=value2
```

All the keys needs to be `prefixed` with `spark`.

then use the spark-submit command like this to pass the properties file.

```
bin/spark-submit --properties-file  propertiesfile.properties
```

Then in the code you can get the keys using below sparkcontext `getConf` method.

```
sc.getConf.get("spark.key1")  // returns value1
```

Once  you get the key values, you can pass use it everywhere.

Comment: Thanks for the response!

I already have a config file in another format(typesafe config). There are several advantages to keeping configs organized instead of putting them as KV pair in a file.

Isn't there a way to have my config file shared with driver too?

Comment: @Cheeko: What do you mean by sharing conf files to Driver? what is there in the conf file? also if  you can read in executor, why dont you read it in driver? read the same in Driver and pass it to executor as broadcast variable.. so you can use it both places..

Comment: The config file is not in a location accessible by all nodes. So I use spark-submit with --files to pass the file to all executors. It looks like --files is not passing the file to driver which is running an another node in "cluster" mode.