# How to pass external configuration file to pyspark(Spark 2.x) program?

Tags: pyspark

When I am running pyspark program interactive shell able to fetch the configuration file(config.ini) inside pyspark script, 
But when I am trying to run same script using Spark submit command with master yarn and cluster deployment mode is cluster it giving me error as config file not exists, I have checked yarn log and able to see same, below is command for running the pyspark job.

```
spark2-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster test.py /home/sys_user/ask/conf/config.ini
```

Comment: With spark2-sumbmit command there is parameter provided properties-file, you can use that to get this properties file available in spark-submit command. e.g.                                        
   spark2-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster --properties-file $CONF_FILE  pyspark_script.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With **spark2-sumbmit** command there is parameter provided properties-file, you can use that to get this properties file available in spark-submit command.

e.g. spark2-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster **--properties-file $CONF_FILE_NAME** pyspark_script.py

Answer (score 0):

Pass the ini file in spark.files parameter

```
.config('spark.files', 'config/local/config.ini') \
```

Read in pyspark:

```
with open(SparkFiles.get('config.ini')) as config_file:
    print(config_file.read())
```

It works for me.