# Sync config files between nodes on hadoop cluster

Tags: hadoop, pyspark

I have a hadoop cluster consisting of 4 nodes on which I am running a pyspark script. I have a config.ini file which contains details like locations of certificates, passwords, server names etc which are needed by the script. Each time this file is updated I need to sync the changes across all 4 nodes. Is there a way to avoid that?

I have needed to sync or update changes to my script. Making them on just one node and running it from there is enough. Is the same possible  for the config file?

Answer (score 1):

The most secure answer is likely to learn [how to use a keystore with spark.](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/security.html#preparing-the-key-stores)

A little less secure but still good. Have you considered you could just put the file in HDFS and then just reference it?  (lower security but easier to use)

Unsecure methods that are easy to use:

You can also [pass it as a file to spark-submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34900023/read-files-sent-with-spark-submit-by-the-driver) to transfer the file for you.

Or you could [add the values to your spark submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40179397/share-config-files-with-spark-submit-in-cluster-mode).